# Slick Slider with Shopify option-select.js: slickGoTo within selectCallback causing Console TypeError on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, slick.js

Apologies if this question is really basic but I'm new to this. I'm modifying [my Shopify store](http://villagebooks.co)'s Theme (made by someone else) to make the Slick slider go to the variant image of the variant selected using Shopify's option-select.js.

You can observe the functionality here: https://villagebooks.co/products/i-d-357

I've done this by putting $('#images_wrap.slider').slick('slickGoTo', variantImagePos); within the selectCallback function. Functionally, it works absolutely fine. But it throws up an error in the Console on load (see below):

Calling slickGoTo within the console works fine. So I'm either making a really basic mistake with calling the function (see code below) or its something to do with the order scripts are loaded on the page.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks!

- Clearing the cache
- Reordering the script tags on the theme page
- wrapping the method in setTimeout(method, 0)

Product page:

```
<select id="product-select" name="id">
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
        <option value="{{ variant.id }}" {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected {% endif %}>{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
{{ 'option_selection.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
<script>
// <![CDATA[
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
    if (variant) {
        var variantImagePos = variant.featured_image.position - 1;
        if (variant.available) {
            // Selected a valid variant that is available.
            $('#add').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled').val('Add to Cart').fadeTo(200,1);
        } else {
            // Variant is sold out.
            $('#add').val('Out of Stock').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled').fadeTo(200,0.25);
        }
        // Whether the variant is in stock or not, we can update the price and compare at price.
        if ( variant.compare_at_price > variant.price ) {
            $('#product_price').html('<span class="product-price on-sale">'+ Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "{{ shop.money_format }}") +'</span>'+'&nbsp;<s class="product-compare-price">'+Shopify.formatMoney(variant.compare_at_price, "{{ shop.money_format }}")+ '</s>');
        } else {
            $('#product_price').html('<span class="product-price">'+ Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "{{ shop.money_format }}") + '</span>' );
        }
        $('#images_wrap.slider').slick('slickGoTo', variantImagePos);
    } else {
        // variant doesn't exist.
        $('#add').val('Select an Option').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled').fadeTo(200,0.5);
    }
}

// initialize multi selector for product
jQuery(function($) {
  new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select", {
    product: {{ product | json }},
    onVariantSelected: selectCallback,
    enableHistoryState: true
  });
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Asides from this error everything works as expected.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slickGoTo' of undefined
    at init.a.fn.slick (plugins.js?580:125)
    at Shopify.OptionSelectors.selectCallback [as onVariantSelected] (i-d-357?_pos=1&_sid=8279d5dd2&_ss=r:901)
    at Shopify.OptionSelectors.updateSelectors (option_selection-fe6b72c2bbdd3369ac0bfefe8648e3c889efca213baefd4cfb0dd9363563831f.js:1)
    at HTMLSelectElement.element.onchange (option_selection-fe6b72c2bbdd3369ac0bfefe8648e3c889efca213baefd4cfb0dd9363563831f.js:1)
    at Object.trigger (plugins.js?580:5)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (plugins.js?580:5)
    at Function.each (plugins.js?580:4)
    at init.each (plugins.js?580:4)
    at init.trigger (plugins.js?580:5)
    at Shopify.OptionSelectors.selectVariant (option_selection-fe6b72c2bbdd3369ac0bfefe8648e3c889efca213baefd4cfb0dd9363563831f.js:1)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `selectCallback` is being executed on page load, *before* `slick` has been initialised. Try adding a check to the callback, such as `if (typeof $().slick === "function") { /* slick has loaded; call it here */ }`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Unfortunately, that solution didn't work :(. The function behaves just as before and the error is still there.

I definitely agree that it's something to do with the order scripts are loaded but even checking the console Network panel it appears they're loading in the correct order. I'm thinking it might be an idea to move that inline script off the page to the separate script.js file?